# Multiple choice quiz app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a rails quiz app, where there will be a question and that particular question will have 4 choices. And below is my approach to the model:

```
rails g Question description:text choice:array
```

I am having trouble getting started. Would this be right approach? If not how should I go about this?

And then there will be category model as which will have has_many association with Question model.

```
rails g Category name:string
```

I will be storing categories foreign key in questions table to show this question is from this particular category.

I am struck at designing the proper Question model. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: When I build this kind of thing I make choice a separate object that has a `question_id`  .  I find that the usual stuff that needs to go with it is something like: text, resource(vid/img), correct or incorrect (bool) and maybe an integer to order the choices and then a question_id reference to.  Then a question `has_many` choices and a choice `belongs_to` question. Then you can just loop through a questions choices.  Just an idea that I have found works well from building 2 elearning systems.

Comment: What data type would you assign to choice column? Considering I'll have to create a separate model for Choice.

Comment: I would not put a choice column in the question table.  You do not need it, just have the relationship set up in the models so a choice belongs_to a question and a question has_many choices.  The choice table would need a question_id reference.

Comment: yeah, I meant a different model like you said `rails g model Choice name: ..` . If this is what you are suggesting to do. What data type would you assign to choice name ? Becuase every question should have 4  choices.

Comment: no name, just something like `text:text`, `correct:boolean`,`position:integer``question:references`.  I use the gem acts_as_list that is why I use `position:integer` for ordering them, if order does not matter you do not need that.  So a choice has text, it is correct or not, it has a position in the order of all the choices for that question (if you need to order them) and it references a question that it belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

You should think of an extra answer model. OK let's go:

Question:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  question_text    :text
#  type             :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answer_options, dependent: :destroy # the questions choices
end
```

AnswerOption:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answer_options
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  answer_text    :text
#  question_id    :integer
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#
class AnswerOption < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :question
   validates :answer_text, presence: true, allow_blank: false
end
```

How to store user answers ? In another model, let us call it a question_answer . -> the answer of an user. User selected some answer_options -> we store these IDs in serialized answer_option_ids attribute.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: question_answers
#
#  id                        :integer          not null, primary key
#  question_id               :integer
#  answer_option_ids         :text
#  user_id                   :integer
#

class QuestionAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :answer_option_ids
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :question_id, :user_id
end
```

in your question.rb add `has_many :question_answers, dependent: :destroy` to get answers to that question